# SSL and httpd.conf

Tags: ssl, https, httpd.conf

I want to allow access to my site with http and https..

Currently if I go to "http://domain.com/img/something.png" the url is broken to "https://domain.comimg/something.png"

*Notice the missing / after domain.com

Can you please help me with this?  Thank you.

here is my httpd.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost localhost:80>
Redirect permanent / https://domain.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost localhost:443>
    RewriteEngine On
            ServerAdmin admin@domain.com
            DocumentRoot /var/www/
            ServerName *.domain.com
            SSLEngine on
            SSLProtocol all
            SSLCertificateFile /usr/local/ssl/crt/certificate.crt
            SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/local/ssl/private/private.key
            SSLCertificateChainFile /usr/local/ssl/crt/intermediate.crt
            ServerPath /var/
            <Directory "/var/www/">
            </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Or should I ONLY use https throughout site?